# Visual Studio 2010 //.NET MVC Application - 404 Error on blank project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I created an empty mvc project in vs2010 and created a view (MessageView), a controller and a model. For some reason when I build my application (having set my view as the start page), it seems to throw a 404 error and appends the following to the URL:

```
http://localhost/MvcApplication1/**Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fMvcApplication1%2fViews%2fMessageView.aspx**
```

Having investigated my web.config file I can see the following piece of code:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

This has been added automatically....Not entirely sure why considering I clicked empty MVC project. Anyone know the cleanest way of fixing this....

**EDIT**

SOLVED: The issue is that I moved MessageView to the Views subdirectory placed there by .NET. I had to place the view at the root of the project directory in order for it to be able to locate and display it. I also had to remove the code above from the web.config file.

How can you get this to work when it is placed within a subdirectory

Comment: While I appreciate you found the correct way to access your URL, it will not work without disabling or fixing FormsAuthentication. Marking this as solved without adding the fact that you removed or fixed the config is showing an incorrect solution, for which there are 2 parts. Please edit your post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the value of the Start Action in the properties of your project on the *web* tab from the default value *Current Page* to something else.

Comment: +1. We usually set ours to "Don't open a page". However, you can use a specific page. But the page should map to a ROUTE that matches your CONTROLLER and ACTION name, not the VIEW file.

Comment: @olivehour: Yeah, *current page* is a relict of the webpages era :)

Comment: Are you using the integrated development web server? Then you are missing the port number in your url. Have you tried to open the root url (/) ?

Comment: I am running all of this locally on my machine without the aid of any integrated web server.

Comment: You have to choose between a locally installed IIS, the integrated web server or a custom webserver in the project properties. So how are you starting your project?

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to access the view, you want to access the controller. This is not a bug, it is how MVC works. Your URL should be:

http://localhost/MvcApplication1/ControllerName

Not

http://localhost/MvcApplication1/Views/MessageView.aspx

**Update**

Here is what is happening. You started with a blank project. This means you do not have an Account controller.

MVC does not allow the web server to expose your raw view files in /Views (/Views/Whatever.aspx). When you try to access it, it causes a 403 forbidden header to be returned.

ASP.NET handles the 403 by redirecting to /Account/LogOn -- the LogOn action method of the AccountController. Since you have a blank project, and there is no AccountController, this is what is causing your 404.

**Another Update**

Just read your SOLVED. Again, you cannot access files in the Views, Controllers, or Models folders. These are special folders used by MVC.

If you want to access a view in a subdirectory, create a subdirectory like /content or /scripts. MVC treats these as normal folders, and you can access whatever you want from them. So, you could put the file in a folder like this:

/SubdirectoryAbc/MessageView.aspx.

You should then be able to access this file using the URL http://localhost/MvcApplication1/SubdirectoryAbc/MessageView.aspx.

However, you would not be able to use the view in a controller action method.

Comment: This is not the issue. Setting the start page does nothing. I am still receiving the error 404. Setting a view as a start page is also valid, even if it isn't how MVC works

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that MVC uses convention for file structure due to its routing. If you are to move the views to another folder, you would need to customize the routing code to to map properly to your folder structure. Honestly though, I don't think it is worth your time.

Answer (score -1):

You can just remove this whole section;

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

This will disable the authentication that has been put onto the site by default with MVC.

Comment: look at the ReturnUrl param in his url. It is trying to access a view.aspx, not a controller.

Comment: This does not remove the error 404 I am receiving - "resource not found"

Comment: @user559142. My answer removes the FormsAuthentication, which is the biggest problem you have, regardless of the additional answers here. You also need to ensure you access it by the Controller as well, as suggested by others. If you do not remove this, attempting to access _any_ url will not work.

Comment: @Olivehour. Regardless of whether the returnurl is correct, nothing will work unless he removes or fixes FormsAuthentication. Your point is valid, however, the question actually asks how to remove the 'bug' of FA, which is added (and not correctly it seems) when setting up a new MVC site.

Comment: @user559142. Please look _closely_ at the various answers that are being given, I believe you need a combination of mine and that of OliveHour. Disable the FormsAuthentication and access the controller.